# How to deploy react js web app with all the components to Amazon Web Services amplify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy React.js web app on Amazon Web Services(AWS) amplify using git hub support. It has been deployed and I got the url but the app doesn't look the same as it does when run locally.

I have followed the steps given [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-intro).

I have used the default build configuration settings and haven't changed anything.

Below is how it looks when run locally.

[image: This is how it should look and looks locally]

Below is how it looks on the link provided by AWS amplify.

[image: This is how it looks]

Can anybody please point out what should I do differently? Do I need to configure something? I have used material-ui and react-bootstrap for frontend components.

App.js - render function

```
render() {
return (
  <div className={classes.container}>
    <AppBar
      className={classes.navbar}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
      position="static"
    >
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          edge="start"
          className={classes.menuButton}
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="menu"
        >
          <img alt="Logo" className={classes.logo} src={Logo} />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6">TIP-TOP NX</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <div className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.frame}>
        <Avatar style={{ margin: "auto", marginTop: "1em" }}>
          <LockOutlined />
        </Avatar>
        <h3 style={{ color: "black", margin: "20px" }}>Sign in</h3>
        <div
          style={{
            marginBottom: "3vh",
            display: this.state.invalid ? "block" : "none",
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="h6" color="error">
            Invalid details!
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          required
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          error={this.state.errors.email.length > 0}
          onChange={this.changeHandler("email")}
        />
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          required
          label="Password"
          variant="outlined"
          type="password"
          error={this.state.errors.password.length > 0}
          onChange={this.changeHandler("password")}
          style={{ marginTop: "1em" }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={this.submitHandler}
          style={{ margin: "5vh auto" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer className={classes.footer}>&copy; 2020-2021</footer>
  </div>
);
}
```

Linked css file:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #555; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #555,
    #000
  ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #555, #000);
}
.logo {
  height: 5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.active {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 80%;
}
.content {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.frame {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px white solid;
  color: black;
}
.footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .frame {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: is your routing defined correctly? probably have problem with production and development routes, so the deployed version is not navigated to i.g. `domain/login` wherein dev mode your app navigates to `localhost/login`

Comment: Besides the hint above, in general, your question is so vague, narrow down the problem to something specific and also include some related code.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I am sorry, I am new to AWS and there's no code to include. This page is the homepage so it lies on localhost/ and not on localhost/login. And the sign in box is visible behind the background and I am able to type in it.

Comment: If you want to see, link: https://testing.d2evjo9ar361pn.amplifyapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an opacity at 1% on your CSS
[image: Picture of console with css open on the login frame]

Is there something that displays a style depending on something ?

Comment: I have 80% opacity in css, I don't know why it shows 1%. I have edited the question and included the code.

Comment: I removed opacity property from css and it works! Thanks, but can you tell me the reason for this?

Comment: Not gonna lie, I wouldn't know.

Maybe the components you're using have some kind of fade-in or computed style that didn't trigger properly ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is happening due to a bug in cssnano package used by react to minify your CSS file during the build. The issue is still happening as of today (December 2020).

The minified version of the CSS file will convert any value in percentages *(xx%)* to 1% during the build, that's why you don't see it in development because you're using the normal (non-minified) version of the CSS file while in development.

The quick fix to this problem is to actually **not** use any % values on CSS, instead use decimals *(0.xx)* and your app should work just fine.

There's a pull regarding this issue on Github, you can check it out here on [cssnano repo](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/pull/881)